# System settings didn't launch on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, system-settings

From today I have this problem on my Ubuntu 16.04:

When I click on **System Settings** it just blinks and nothing happens.

I tried this but it didn't helped me:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the result of opening a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T and issuing the command `unity-control-center --overview` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Now it's working if I'm using `unity-control-center --overview`. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! See my answer to address the root cause. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since it launches properly from the terminal, you can

Option 1) simply create a new shortcut for it as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) or

Option 2) repair the existing shortcut at `usr/share/applications/unity-control-center.desktop` which on my system looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=System Settings
Icon=preferences-system
Exec=unity-control-center --overview
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=unity-control-center
```

Option 3) reinstall the package with:
`sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity-control-center`

Any of these approaches should work.